# Не работают скрипты внутри html документа

Tags: javascript, html

Скрипт не работает если я пишу его внутри html документа (см. скрипт перед `</body>`) Но при этом работают любые внешние скрипты (см. скрипт "personalLessonScript.js")

---

А еще, внешние скрипты перестают работать, если их поместить куда-либо, кроме как перед `</body>`
Что я делаю не так?

Код html документа:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  <!-- lib -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../lib/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- main -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../css/style.css">
  <title>name</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- UI bar -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="progressBlock">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col mt-3" style="text-align:right">
            <a href="../../../learn_base.html"><img src="../../start.png" alt="" width="30" height="30"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8 mt-4">
            <div class="backProgressline"><div class="progressLine"></div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col mt-3" style="text-align:left">
            <img src="../../fin.png" alt="" width="30" height="30">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col">
        <img src="../../../img/lvl.png" alt="" width="80" height="80">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="dis">Текст</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- menu bar -->
  <div class="menuBar">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <a href="l2.html" id="nextBtn1"><div class="lessonBtn">Далее</div></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/index.js"></script>
  <!-- lib -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.localStorage.setItem("lesson", "1");
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="personalLessonScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: видимо некоторые скрипты зависят от jquery и bootstrap, которые как раз нужно бы в head загружать

Comment: Ваш вышеприведённый скрипт (`window.localStorage.setItem("lesson", "1");`) работает.

Comment: @СергейМишин к сожалению нет, alert не работает

Comment: @InDevX у меня он почему то не работает, и даже если вместо него я напишу просто alert('fff')

Comment: В консоли есть ошибки?

Comment: @InDevX Только одна, "HTML-документ не содержит объявления кодировки символов"

Comment: jquery всегда должны подключаться первыми, они могут использоваться в других скриптах.. Вы же его практически последним грузите. перенесите `jquery-3.3.1.min.js`, `bootstrap.min.js` в `<head>`

Comment: @InDevX перенес и теперь у меня перестал работать внешний скрипт "personalLessonScript.js" и старые проблемы тоже не решились

Comment: Может быть проблема в браузере либо блокировщике сценариев типо adblock? Также попробуйте почистить кэш браузера.

Comment: @Skrillexazem Вот, я немного перефразировал вопрос https://clck.ru/FvgG

Comment: 404 ссылка нерабочая.

Comment: @Skrillexazem https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/979375/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-cordova-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, что все дело в строчке `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy">`
Которая автоматически создается в index.html при создании проекта cordova.
Content-Security-Policy запрещает выполнение "опасных" скриптов