# Не работают некоторые скрипты в cordova проекте

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Есть cordova проект, ничего необычного, все стандартно.
Скрипты о которых я говорю любые, т.е. тот же alert работать не будет(см. ниже)

---

Проблема в том, что скрипты написанные внутри html документов не работают, при работе со всеми, что у меня есть, браузерами(chrome, edge, mozilla) **на десктопе**.

---

**НО** работают внешние скрипты, подключаемые как файлы **и только** в mozilla.

---

**НО** все прекрасно работает в предпросмотре проекта на телефоне через phonegup

---

Что за дела, что я упустил?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что все дело в строчке `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy">`
Которая автоматически создается в index.html при создании проекта cordova.
Content-Security-Policy запрещает выполнение "опасных" скриптов